# How to remove everything from body apart of one tag with perticular class with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

This  will be probable quite odd question. But i thought I will give it a go.

Is there a way to remove everything from body apart of one tag that has particular class?

in my case it is an a tag with href.

I need to "fish out" the a tag and then display on DOM just the href tag in lets say p tag.

```
<body>
 <a class="avatar_user_name" href="/product/xyz">Title</a>

...other body tags and text

<a class="avatar_user_name" href="/product/abc">Title</a>
</body>
```

and as a result I need to have something like this

```
<body>
<p>xyz</p>
<p>abc</p>
</body>
```

Thank you for any help in advance
Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this will work, but worth a try?

```
<script type="text/javascript>
$(document).ready(function() {

    // obtain list of links
    var a = [];
    $('a.avatar_user_name').each(function(i,e) {
        a[i] = $(this).attr('href');
    });
    // build up a new page
    $('body').empty();
    for (var i = 0, j = a.length; i < j; i++) {
        $('body').append('<p>' + a[i] + '</p>');
    } 
});
</script>
```

Let us know if this works, I'd be curious if it does!  Good luck!

Comment: Wow, I'm truly amazed. This works perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: Nice - didn't know about the empty method. I was thinking about posting an answer using the not selectors and the remove method - this is much better than that would have been.

Answer (score -1):

I can't think of any way of doing this. I think a better option would be either grab or code the values of the 2 links in JS, remove everything inside the body and then add the links back in. Maybe not the most efficient, but usually people don't remove *everything* inside a body tag either.

Another option is to add a tag around everything else within the body tag (if you page structure is as simple as your example in the question). This tag doesn't need to be a formatting tag, but could be a span with an ID. In this case you'd just remove everything inside this tag.